# Custom keyboard toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, keyboard

Im creating a toolbar for the keyboard but I dont know why my toolbar is positioning in the top of the current view. I need to put the toolbar at the top of the keyboard
[This is how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d1UT.png)

This is the code

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct KeyboardObserving: ViewModifier {

@State var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0
@State var keyboardAnimationDuration: Double = 0
@State var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
  content
    .padding([.bottom], keyboardHeight)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea((keyboardHeight > 0) ? [.bottom] : [])
    .animation(.easeOut(duration: keyboardAnimationDuration))
    .onReceive(
      NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification)
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main),
      perform: updateKeyboardHeight
    )
}

func updateKeyboardHeight(_ notification: Notification) {
  guard let info = notification.userInfo else { return }
  // Get the duration of the keyboard animation
  keyboardAnimationDuration = (info[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double) ?? 0.25
    
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
                currentHeight = keyboardSize.height
        print("currentheiht \(currentHeight)") // output 336.0
            }

  guard let keyboardFrame = info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else { return }
  // If the top of the frame is at the bottom of the screen, set the height to 0.
  if keyboardFrame.origin.y == UIScreen.main.bounds.height {
    keyboardHeight = 0
  } else {
    // IMPORTANT: This height will _include_ the SafeAreaInset height.
    keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.height
    print("keyboad \(keyboardHeight)")// output 336.0
  }
}
}

    extension View {
      func keyboardObserving() -> some View {
        self.modifier(KeyboardObserving())
      }
    }
```

Comment: check  text field `inputAccessoryView`.

Comment: The textfield in SwiftUI doesn't have the certain method.  @RTXGamer

Comment: then Wrap textfield with an input accessory view using UIViewRepresentable